# How to create a java deamon and how to interact?

Tags: java, php, daemon

I need to create a java program which runs all the time since the boot, and I'd like to be able to comunicate with it when some some event (inputs from a hosted php server) happen.

 In my mind there should be a daemon running and a way to give him some instructions, any suggestion? Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: There are tools that turn Java executables into Windows services or Linux demons. That's probably what you should be looking for. You can simply look at application server implementations (e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish) and see what they use.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an http endpoint and then do a post to it with the info that you want the service to handle